# If I am connected with two network then which network will be used for communication?

Tags: routing, default-gateway

First I connect with a WIFI (to get internet connectivity) and then I connect with my company's network using Pulse Secure. When I do `ipconfig` then I get an output something like below:

```
C:\Users\himanshu.agrawal>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : groupinfra.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5ae5:4ee4:b357:f578%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.208.102.212
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ed38:ca7c:4e6f:4559%17
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.231
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

What I want to understand that:

1. When I am accessing internet sites then which network will be used - WIFI network or my company's network?
2. I know that the target website can see the IP address of the machine from which request has originated, so in my case the target website - - WIFI network (192.168.0.231) or my company's network (10.208.102.212)?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers are off-topic here. Also, with the Pulse Secure, it is probably disabling split-tunneling, so your only connection is to the company network.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-homed host uses *routing* to determine the interface and gateway to use for any given packet - just like a single-homed one, but in a less trivial way.

Generally, longer, more specific prefixes take precedence over shorter, more general ones. If there's a tie, for instance with two default routes, then the interface metric/cost decides (lower value = higher precedence).

Check your local routing table, for a Windows host using `route print`, to see the used prefixes, gateways, metrics and interfaces.

Yes, this is exactly what a router does as well. The difference is that a router *forwards packets between interfaces* which a host doesn't. That's why some prefer the alternative name *gateway* for a router.